# Android verify CA signature in X.509 Certificate

Tags: java, android, digital-signature, ecdsa, spongycastle

I have a Root CA certificate and a User certificate that has been signed by the CA.  Under Windows using Certutil or OpenSSL I can verify that the CA's signature on the User certificate signature is OK.  Now I am trying to verify the same signature under Android.

I use Spongy Castle, though I am not sure that it is totally necessary for this step.  I use ECDH 384-bit key pairs.  The signature is "SHA384WITHECDSA".  I can generate a self-signed certificate and verify its signature either by the certificate.verify method or by calculating the signature:

```
public static byte[] GenerateMyClientCertificate()
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
    {
        // Create the keys
        KeyPairGenerator ClientkeyPair = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDH", "SC");
        ECGenParameterSpec ecParamSpec2 = new ECGenParameterSpec("P-384");
        ClientkeyPair.initialize(ecParamSpec2);
        KeyPair clientKeyPair = ClientkeyPair.generateKeyPair();

        PublicKey publicKey = clientKeyPair.getPublic();
        PrivateKey privateKey = clientKeyPair.getPrivate();

        X509Certificate x509cert = null;
        byte[] derCert = null;
        // generate the certificate
        try {
            x509cert = generateV3Certificate(clientKeyPair);
            derCert = x509cert.getEncoded();

        //Certificate test using verify:
        x509cert.checkValidity(new Date());
        x509cert.verify(x509cert.getPublicKey(), "SC");  //This cert is self-signed...
        System.out.println("valid certificate generated");

        //Another test: (verify not using cert.verify but rather calculating the signature)
        Signature verifier = Signature.getInstance("SHA384WITHECDSA", "SC");
        boolean result=false;
        verifier.initVerify(x509cert.getPublicKey()); // This cert is self-signed
        verifier.update(x509cert.getTBSCertificate());  //TBS is to get the "To Be Signed" part of the certificate - .getEncoded() gets the whole cert, which includes the signature
        result = verifier.verify(x509cert.getSignature());
        if (result == false)
        {
            System.out.println("signature validation failed");
        }
        //end of another verification
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //
    }
    return derCert;
} //GenerateMyClientCertificate
```

In the same way, I can check the CA certificate, which is also a self-signed certificate:

```
//Certificate validity test using verify: -- This seems to work well for self-signed certificates...
        RootCaX509Cert.checkValidity(new Date());
        RootCaX509Cert.verify(RootCaX509Cert.getPublicKey(), "SC");  //This cert is self-signed...
        System.out.println("valid certificate generated");

        //Another test: (verify not using cert.verify but rather calculating the signature)
        Signature verifier = Signature.getInstance("SHA384WITHECDSA", "SC");
        boolean result=false;
        verifier.initVerify(RootCaX509Cert.getPublicKey()); // This cert is self-signed
        verifier.update(RootCaX509Cert.getTBSCertificate());  //TBS is to get the "To Be Signed" part of the certificate - .getEncoded() gets the whole cert, which includes the signature
        result = verifier.verify(RootCaX509Cert.getSignature());
        if (result == false)
        {
            System.out.println("signature validation failed");
        }
```

Now I want to check the User certificate, using the public key of the CA certificate.  But neither of the above verify methods work:

```
        //Certificate validity test using verify: -- This seems to work well for self-signed certificates...
        ServerX509Cert.checkValidity(new Date());
        ServerX509Cert.verify(RootCaX509Cert.getPublicKey(), "SC");  //This cert was signed by CA
        System.out.println("valid certificate generated");

        //Another test: (verify not using cert.verify but rather calculating the signature)
        Signature verifier = Signature.getInstance("SHA384WITHECDSA", "SC");
        boolean result=false;
        verifier.initVerify(RootCaX509Cert.getPublicKey()); // This cert is signed by CA
        verifier.update(ServerX509Cert.getTBSCertificate());  //TBS is to get the "To Be Signed" part of the certificate - .getEncoded() gets the whole cert, which includes the signature
        result = verifier.verify(ServerX509Cert.getSignature());
        if (result == false)
        {
            System.out.println("signature validation failed");
        }
```

So currently I can only check self-signed certificates :( 
I would have thought that using RootCaX509Cert.getPublicKey() as the key here would have worked, but it does not.  Maybe I misunderstand how this CA signature verification should be done?